# Controller implementing interface not instantiated after adding @Validated spring annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have a below RestController where I am trying to validate search() method input parameter map for empty. However during unit testing this RestController is not instantiated when it implements ServiceIF interface. If I comment implementing interface then controller is instantiated and validation works properly. I do not understand why annotating @Validated for a class which implements some interface does not work.

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class MyServiceImpl implements ServiceIF{

    @RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> search(@RequestBody @NotEmpty Map<String, String> body) {
    }
}
```

I am writing a below unit test to validate for empty map :

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class})
public class MyServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceIF controller;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                                    .setControllerAdvice(new InputValidationsExceptionHandler())
                                    .build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
            mockMvc = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearchInvalid() throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);

        //Test invalid case
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/search").content(data)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                                .andDo(print())
                                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

    }
}
```

Comment: I had exact same issue. When you delete @Validated annotation the endpoint registered otherwise always return 404. Unfortunately, I did not find a solution so I write my own validation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in the `ServiceIF` interface. If `ServiceIF.search` method parameter has no annotation `@NotEmpty`. You will get the exception by application start:

> javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter
>   constraint configuration

see [this spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-inheritance)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried this already but still doesn't work. Also I don't see any ConstraintDeclarationException.